# Determinant of $\lambda I + A^TA$

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

What properties $\lambda I + A^TA$ have? I know that $A^T A$ is positive semi-definite, and symmetric. I want to show that the determinant of $\lambda I + A^TA$ decreases as $\lambda$ increases!

Comment: If $A = I$, then $A^TA = I$ so $\lambda I + A^TA = (\lambda + 1)I$; the determinant of $(1 + \lambda)I$ is $(1 + \lambda)^n$, where the size of $A$ is $n$.  $(1 + \lambda)^n$ increases with $\lambda$ if $\lambda > 0$.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an orthogonal change of basis $A^TA$ becomes a diagonal matrix $D$ with nonnegative entries $d_1,\dots,d_n$.
The question is then whether
$$
f(\lambda)
=
\det(\lambda I+D)
=
\prod_{i=0}^n(\lambda+d_i)
$$
increases or decreases as $\lambda$ increases.
For $\lambda\geq0$, we see that each term in the product is positive and increases with $\lambda$ so $f(\lambda)$ increases as $\lambda$ increases.
(That is, $f'(\lambda)>0$ for $\lambda>0$.)

But it is possible that $f$ is decreasing for sufficiently negative arguments.
For example, if $n$ is even and $D=0$, you can see that $f(\lambda)=\lambda^n$ is a decreasing function in the area $\lambda\leq0$.